# How to read analog sensor data with different timers in arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, timers

I have three analog sensors like voltage, temperature and pressure. I need to measure the voltage and temperature every 10 ms and I need to measure the pressure alone every 30 ms by using the timers in an Arduino.

How can I do this?

Comment: see the BlinkWithoutDelay example in Arduino IDE Examples menu

Comment: Have you seen this library? https://www.avdweb.nl/arduino/timing/virtualdelay

Comment: please add your code to your post

Comment: You only need one timer for this, which triggers every 10ms. Then read pressure only every third time. Or you can just use `millis()` or `micros()` depending on the rest of your code. Please share that code and explain what it should do

Comment: start with BlinkWithoutDelay as @Juraj mentioned ... do not delete any part of the code ... add a counter variable and set it to zero... go to the part of the program where the LED is updated ... add a function to measure voltage and temperature ... if the counter = 0, then measure pressure ... increment counter ... if the counter = 3, then set counter to zero ... when everything works  then change the delay variable from 500 to 10

Comment: ". . . by using the timers in Arduino." You have multiple options depending on how deep you need to go for this exercise, listed here in order of increasing complexity. (1) The simple recording of the start time of an event and testing to see if its time slot has expired as in the already mentioned "blink without delay" sketch. (2) Using ready made timer libraries which can call user specified functions at defined intervals etc. and (3) direct configuration of hardware timers to trigger interrupt service routines, directly manipulate gpio pins etc.

Answer (score 1):

May this help as starting point! Not tested

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(A0, INPUT);
  pinMode(A1, INPUT);
  pinMode(A2, INPUT);
}

unsigned long previousMillis1;
unsigned long previousMillis2;

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if (currentMillis - previousMillis1 >= 10) {
    int val1 = analogRead(A0);
    int val2 = analogRead(A1);
    Serial.print("Values from A0 and A1: ");
    Serial.print(val1);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.println(val2);
    previousMillis1 = currentMillis;
  }

  if (currentMillis - previousMillis2 >= 30) {
    int val3 = analogRead(A2);
    Serial.print("Value from A2: ");
    Serial.println(val3);
    previousMillis2 = currentMillis;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind help Mr. Carlos Costa, but i am in need to use timer 1 or 2. without using millis i have to read the sensor data

Comment: Presumably it is a school project. Are you allowed to use ready made libraries or do you have to use direct configuration of the timer's hardware registers? Which Arduino are you using? In any case, the datasheet for the microcontroller is a good (but heavy going) start.